# Sencha architect bug - seems to not update the views list in the app.js file

Tags: sencha-architect

I think I've noticed a problem in Sencha Architect whereby the app.js views collection property is not updating.  I've removed all my views and added 2 new ones, but the views array is not reflecting what views I really have in my project.  Seems to be losing track of what it has somehow.

Has anyone noticed this?  Is there a fix or work-around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting Architect. If the problem persists, check to see if you have added all your views in the "view" config under "Application" in your inspector.

Comment: Restarting obviously fixed the problem but not sure why it got into this state.

Answer (score 0):

For me a restart *didn't* fix it (in Architect v2.2.3) so I closed Architect and manually edited the **metadata/Application** file to remove the defunct views and then they were gone when I restarted Architect.